# How to sort by JSF label in sortable datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jpa-2.0

I am showing a (language specific) label for values in a column. The column is sortable and the JSF label is different from the database value. I am using a primefaces datatable with pagination.

How can I sort by label and not by the database value? Is there any kind of translation possible so my JPA criteria knows about the different value?

Sorting it in-memory is not an option since the dataset might be huge and I only want to display a subset (pagination size is e.g. 10 items per page)

Comment: can't you use `sortBy="#{myRow.mylabel}"` attribute of `<p:column ` ? just populate your label value into a field of the object that represents your row...

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, I tried that already. But the label is not stored in the database and that is where the sorting takes place (well, in the generated statement). So the point is: the database is not aware of the label the users sees. however the users are wondering about a wrong sorting behavior

Comment: so place this label into your object that represents row in table... , y not?

Comment: this would not be conform with the I18N internationalization mechnism of JSF and the label of an attribute value should not be hardcoded in the object since the labels are for the GUI only.what happens if you use the same data model in another GUI?

Comment: you should translate your label on the server side from your properties files that are used by the JSF... use ResourceBundle.getBundle("some.package.resources.YourTexts",yourLocale)...

Comment: The sort is done by the natural order of the data type of the Column, the Comparable of the Data Type of the Column, or a provided Comparator to the Column.  The label of the column is irrelevant and is customisable via a ResourceBundle.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible to achieve what you are looking for.

Your database cannot sort unless it knows what the value is. You can translate the label and sort after loading from database, but you dont want in-memory sort due to resource constraints.

The best solution would be to implement localization solution in database. Then your db could look up the translation for each label and apply sorting. Personally I believe this is the way to go when localizing any application as it allows for easy translations by end-users. You could even write Java resource bundle provider that does db lookups instead of referring to filesystem bundles.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example of lazyload here:

- [Part 4 – Lazy Loading and Pagination with JSF 2.1 / Primefaces 3.5 DataTable and Form validation](http://www.simtay.com/part-4-lazy-loading-and-pagination-with-jsf-2-1-primefaces-3-5-datatable-and-form-validation/).

You can write a custom sort following the method from that link.

Comment: Is there anyway you could copy some of the code from that article into your answer? Otherwise if the link goes away your answer becomes useless to anyone else in the future.